# Adjust workspace size

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[I have read](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3013527)
that the default workspace size is about 227". This is much to large for me as I
am working with Letter (8.5 x 11) documents.

The effect of this is that the scrollbar is very small

[image: small]

And any movement is greatly exaggerated. How can I adjust the workspace to a
smaller size?

Comment: To be honest it never occoured to ne anybody uses those handles for navigation especially because the pan and zoom tools are so accessible and superior in every way. In fact i can not say i have used those handles in any app for 10 years now for other than a indicator that the area can scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading
[a comment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/36667#comment51291_36667)
I found a workaround.

You can use the *Pan Tool*, officially known as the *Hand Tool*. You can hold
space and it switches to it temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, **you can't**. It is not possible to alter the work area size in Adobe Illustrator. It is hard coded into the application.

Answer (score 0):

The Hand Pan option works for me in Illustrator CC if I depress <kbd>Shift + Alt</kbd> and left click button on the touchpad on my laptop. This might only be due to the lack of the use of the mouse and touchpad option.